# jsonb_array_elements omitting missing array keys

Tags: postgresql

I have a json object which contains a list of arrays like so :

```
{"result" : {
 "address_components": [
      {
        "types": ["route"],
        "long_name": "Church Road",
        "short_name": "Church Rd"
      },
      {
        "types": ["administrative_area_level_1","political"],
        "long_name": "England",
        "short_name": "England"
      },
      {
        "types": ["country", "political"],
        "long_name": "United Kingdom",
        "short_name": "GB"
      },
      {
        "types": [ "postal_code"],
        "long_name": "TS18 1TW",
        "short_name": "TS18 1TW"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is only an example - there are many more fields that I wish to extract, but each object is inconsistent and doesn't always contain i.e. a "postal_code" array.

I'm trying to extract each `types ->> 0` as the field name and the `long_name` as the value. So far I have:

```
 SELECT full_response,
       obj ->>'long_name' as aug_premise
    , obj1 ->> 'long_name' as aug_street_number
    , obj2 ->> 'long_name' as aug_street_name
    , obj3 ->> 'long_name' as aug_sublocality
    , obj4 ->> 'long_name' as aug_locality
    , obj5 ->> 'long_name' as aug_town_city
    , obj6 ->> 'long_name' as aug_city_county
    , obj7 ->> 'long_name' as aug_region
    , obj8 ->> 'long_name' as aug_country
    , obj9 ->> 'long_name' as aug_post_code


    FROM augmentation.g_placesapi_responses,
         jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj(elem)
         ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj1(elem1)
         ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj2(elem2)
         ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj3(elem3)
         ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj4(elem4)
         ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj5(elem5)
         ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj6(elem6)
        ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj7(elem7)
        ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj8(elem8)
        ,jsonb_array_elements(full_response -> 'result' -> 'address_components') obj9(elem9)

    WHERE TRUE
    AND elem -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'premise'
    AND elem1 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'street_number'
    AND elem2 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'route'
    AND elem3 -> 'types' ->> 0 in ('sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1')
    AND elem4 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'locality'
    AND elem5 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'postal_town'
    AND elem6 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'administrative_area_level_2'
    AND elem7 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'administrative_area_level_1'
    AND elem8 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'country'
    AND elem9 -> 'types' ->> 0 = 'postal_code'
```

This seems to work when I remove some of the elements, however it only works where the named array actually exists. So for example if there is no array where `types->> 0` = "postal_code" ,
then the entire row is omitted.

The overall output I'm trying to create is, for multiple rows, the types->>0 as the header, and the associated long_name as the value, like so:

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+-----+
|    route    | administrative_area_level_1 | etc |
+-------------+-----------------------------+-----+
| Church Road | England                     | etc |
| London Road | Scotland                    | etc |
| <None>      | England                     | etc |
+-------------+-----------------------------+-----+
```

Here's a DB fiddle that contains three json documents. The first two have fields 'route' and 'administrative_area_level_1' and show in the results. However the third json document doesn't have a 'route' array, and therefore doesn't show in the results:

[db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/2730)

How can I amend this (or completely redesign, perhaps using a stored function) to show the rows even where some have 'missing' arrays?

Please note I do not have the option to upgrade my postgres.

Comment: Why are you unnesting the same array over and over again? A single `jsonb_array_elements` should be enough

Comment: It's totally unclear to me what output you want to get. Your unnesting (which will duplicate the information) indicates you want the elements as rows, but then you treat every row like it was a column. So please **[edit]** your question and add an example on what output you are looking for. [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=10eec88a3ccc8f8861ddb1349b7af21b

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name I've added the output to the question. I'm trying to extract each sub-array within `address_components` into a separate column, with the `types->>0` i.e. "route" as the column name and the `long_name` i.e. "Church Road" as the row value.

Comment: Thanks for the db_fiddle! It's not quite what I need - does the table above make it clearer?

Comment: Wo where does premise or street_number come from? Those aren't in your sample data. But you can't define a column name based on the value of another column.

Comment: Apologies - I've changed the table output, and altered the db_fiddle to have three json documents, but the third one doesn't have a sub-array containing "route" as the type, and therefore doesn't show in the results, but I'd like it to show but with null/none in the 'route' column.